# Streaming JSON with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I have been given a task — I'm trying to make routes/endpoints using just Node to better demostrate what is happening under the covers with Express. But I have to use streams.

I have two routes `GET /songs` and `GET/refresh-songs` with the following requirements:

> We need the following two endpoints:
>
> GET /songs
>    GET /refresh-songs
>
> All endpoints should return JSON with the correct headers
>
> /songs should...
>
> stream data from a src/data/songs.json file
>        not crash the server if that file or directory doesn't exist
>
> bonus points for triggering refresh code in this case
>        bonus points for compressing the response
>
> /refresh-songs should...
>
> return immediately
>         it should not hold the response while songs are being refreshed
>
> return a 202 status code with a status JSON response
>
> continue getting songs from iTunes
>         frontend should have
>
> UI/button to trigger this endpoint

This is what I have so far in my `server.js` file where my endpoints will live.

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse: parseUrl } = require('url');
const { createGzip } = require('zlib');
const { songs, refreshSongs } = require('./songs');
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = fs.createReadStream('./src/data/songs.jso')

const PORT = 4000;

const server = createServer(({ headers, method, url }, res) => {
  const baseResHeaders = {
    // CORS stuff is gone. :(
    'content-type' : 'application/json'
  };

  // Routing ¯\_(ツ)_ /¯
  //

  var path = url.parseUrl(url).pathname;

  function onRequest(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, 'Content-Type': baseResHeaders['content-type']);
    stream.on('data', function(err, data){
      if (err) {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write('File not found');
        refreshSongs();
      } else {
        response.write(createGzip(data))
      }
      response.end()
    })
  }

  switch (path) {
    case '/songs':
      onRequest()
      break;
    case '/refresh-songs':
      onRequest()
      break;

  }

server.on('listening', () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

I am wondering if I am wiring the `onRequest` method I created correctly and if the switch statement is correctly going to intercept those URL's

Comment: Please indicate where you're having problems; what you're expecting and what you're getting, etc.. [ask] has some great tips on how to create a good question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks i updated my question!